# How can I calculate the mean over a series of specific, constant width column ranges?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas 1D DataFrame (columns: float, values: float) like this one:

```
    1.0     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4     1.5     1.6     1.7     1.8
0   1.0     2.0     5.0     4.0     3.0     NaN     1.0     7.0     NaN
```

I'd like to calculate the mean over specific row ranges. `NaN` shall be considered as `0.0`. E.g. in case of constant column ranges relative to the overall column range (`1.0 - 1.2`, `1.3 - 1.5`, `1.6 - 1.9`) I'd like to get the following DataFrame as result:

```
    1.0     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4     1.5     1.6     1.7     1.8
0   2.66    2.66    2.66    2.33    2.33    2.33    2.66    2.66    2.66
```

What's the most performant and memory aware implementation to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want `mean` per each 3 values of columns, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `axis='columns'` and integer division of `np.arange` by length of columns and also replace missing values to `0` before:

```
df = df.fillna(0).groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3, axis='columns').transform('mean')
print (df)
        1.0       1.1       1.2       1.3       1.4       1.5       1.6  \
0  2.666667  2.666667  2.666667  2.333333  2.333333  2.333333  2.666667   

        1.7       1.8  
0  2.666667  2.666667
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df.columns)))
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]

print (np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3)
[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2]
```

Comment: Human readable is `axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}`, means `axis='columns'`.